# upload file and display, but save to database after user submit

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I have an image upload form. When a user selects an image, the image will be displayed, along with a new input Form for title, and submit button. I know how to do this.

Idea being, save the image and title only if user clicks final submit.

To do this, should I save the image and update the database in the first step itself? or can I upload to temp, and if user submits in step two, proceed to move the file to final destination and update db?

Comment: both options are fine. in either case if the user leaves after step one, you need to clean up file\data. I would do it all in one step.

Comment: @Dagon Question was more like, how to do it all in one step. in the form in step 2, just the path to file is enough ?

Comment: just add the file upload and the title input in the same form

Comment: @Dagon Yes offcourse. I was hoping (need) to split it into two steps.

Comment: " Question was more like, how to do it all in one step." confused me you did

Comment: @Dagon my bad. I must have been thinking of some other thing when I wrote that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have your form wait for the user submit. Otherwise your database will overflow with the undone (or temp) title and image name. When user click submit then the upload process is begin and test the upload result if true=insert into your_table values(...).

Comment: yes, thats what worries me. I do want to do this in two steps. to keep teh form clean and simple. And I am not sure how to split this process  in two steps.

Answer (score 0):

why 2 steps ? if you are saving the image just to display the image to the user, you can use HTML5 File Reader API which displays images from user's machine before uploading to server . . . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader

Comment: browser compatibility is poor, from what they say on the page.

Comment: it works on html5 enabled browsers . . .but IE support is very poor (not supported in IE 9)... But, you can work around by using feature detection library like [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) and add appropriate file input elements depending on browser compatibility